# Existe alguma maneira de exibir o tamanho da string em um resultado MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Existe alguma maneira de exibir o tamanho da string em um resultado MYSQL?

Eu preciso, por exemplo, saber o tamanho de uma determinada string retornada em um `SELECT` com `group_concat`.

O que eu quero seria mais ou menos parecido com esse exemplo:

```
SELECT "nome", FUNCAO_PARA_OBTER_TAMANHO("nome")
```

Gostaria de retornar algo como:

```
 nome | 4
```

Comment: length(nome) nao retorna ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para saber o número de caracteres pode usar `char_lenght()` no exemplo retorna 4 pois o retorno é baseado nos caracteres e não nos bytes como faz `lenght()` que retorna 6(número de bytes);

```
select CHAR_LENGTH("ação")

select LENGTH("ação")
```

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ea7e/3)

Comment: Interessante. Parece que é mais conveniente por causa do `UTF-8` e afins!

Answer (score 5):

Não sei se é isso que você esta procurando

```
SELECT nome, LENGTH(nome) as tamanho FROM ....
```

Answer (score 5):

Depende de qual medida deseja obter.

Existem as funções `LENGTH()` e `CHAR_LENGTH()`.

A função `LENGTH()` calcula a medida em bytes.

A função `CHAR_LENGTH()` calcula a medida em caracteres.

Numa comparação um tanto grosseira com o PHP, `LENGTH()` equivale ao`strlen()` e `CHAR_LENGTH()` equivale ao `mb_strlen()`.

Um curiosidade interessante, ambas as funções permitem fazer um `cast` do parâmetro, definindo o tipo de charset.

```
select length(_utf8 '言葉'), char_length(_utf8 '言葉')

select length(_utf8 'ação'), char_length(_utf8 'ação')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Poupou-me de fazer uma pergunta. Quando eu fiz `LENGTH('é')` retornou `2`. Deveria retornar `1`. Mas com o `CHAR_LENGTH` foi certinho.

Comment: O length() retorna o tamanho real em bytes, o que é muito diferente de quantidade de caracteres. Acho melhor não falar muito de bytes senão aparece o cara do kib, mib, gib.. rsrssr